# How to call Perl variable in R and Shell script?

Tags: r, shell, perl

> I have a Shell script and a R script both link with a Perl script. In Perl script there is user define path I want to use that path for Shell script and R script too. what changes are required?
>   this is Perl script :

```
print "Enter the path to your input file:";
chomp(my $user_path = <STDIN>);
my $path = $user_path // $default_path;  # $path  is path for Perl script
print "The path we'll use is: $path";
........................
........
```

> This is R script:

```
x <- read.table($path."/text.txt", header=F) # how to introduce $path as path for R script
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(x, .(x$V1,x$V2, x$V3), nrow)
..............
.............
```

> ($path) is working for Perl script but it is not working in R. I want to call Perl variable ($path) in R and Shell script.How to use $path as path in R and in Shell script ?

Comment: Can you explain how the Perl script, the shell script and the R script are working together? Does the Perl script call the shell script? Does the Perl script call the R script? The easiest way would be to pass the `$path` as command line parameter to the shell script and the R script.

Comment: @Corion There is one Perl script  first it call a shell script and then call R script.

Comment: So what's stopping you from passing `$path` to the shell script , and then from the shell script to the R script?

Comment: I save the path in a variable $path (in Perl script). so for Perl script its work properly but when Shell script or R script come it can not detect $path so it gives error. see edit in R script :                                                                                                         So, I don't know how to introduce $path as path to Shell script and R script.

Comment: Yes. Variables are not shared between scripts. You need to explicitly pass them around. In your Perl code, you launch the shell script. There you must pass the `$path` variable as a parameter, and in the shell script, you must pass it on to the R script. You can also use the environment to pass the value: `$ENV{ MY_APP_PATH } = $path`, and then in R `Sys.getenv(c("MY_APP_PATH"))`

Comment: In perl, call other scripts and specify the path as an argument to these scripts.

Comment: @Nic3500 I want to make it automatic, path will provide only one time and it will automatically pass to other scripts. Is this possible?

Comment: look at how to call external script from Python.  Python script reads the directory, then calls he perl with directory as argument, then calls the R with directory as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just use $path as argument on your `system` or `exec` ini perl. It'll send arg to shell script, then use it as arg for `Rscript`.

For example, I have 3 script. Here we go.

```
root@analist:~/test# cat file.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Input file
print "[Perl] Enter file:";
chomp(my $filepath = <STDIN>);
#Send to bash script
my @cmd = ('./file.sh');
push @cmd, $filepath;
system(@cmd);
root@analist:~/test# cat file.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "[Bash] Filename: $1"
Rscript file.R $1
root@analist:~/test# cat file.R
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
fileTxt <- args[1]
cat(paste('[R] File:', fileTxt, '\n'))
root@analist:~/test# ./file.pl
[Perl] Enter file:test.txt
[Bash] Filename: test.txt
[R] File: test.txt
```

I hope this answer can help.

Comment: How this program will work? will you please elaborate.